# (FOLLOW-UP) Header-only bigint library written in c++20

Tags: c++, beginner, c++20, bigint

This question is a follow up of [Header only bigint library written in c++20](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/260335/header-only-bigint-library-written-in-c20/).

I've made all (or almost all) the corrections suggested in the answers, plus some minor change here and there and a modification in the division algorithm. Instead of a lot of constructors, now there are only two template construcors, limited by concepts. The reason I do this instead of just defining a constructor for the biggest types is because I want the bigint class to work seamlessly with all the builtin integer types.

I made a follow-up question for two reasons:

1. One of the people who replied said that he/she's "sure there is more".
2. If everything else is mostly correct, I would like some comments on the algoritms that I used (If there are better choices, if they can be optimized in some places etc.), particularly for `stobi` and the division algorithm (but also for the other stuff).

**WARNING:** don't use GCC 11.1 to compile this, the compilation will stop with an internal compiler error because of [this bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=100367). Use GCC 10 instead, or GCC 11.2 when it will come out.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <cmath>
#include <compare>
#include <concepts>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using std::uint_least64_t;
using std::uint32_t;
using std::uintmax_t;
using size_type = uint_least64_t;

class bigint {
    
    static const uint_least64_t BASE=static_cast<uint_least64_t>(std::numeric_limits<uint32_t>::max())+1;
    static const uint_least64_t DIGITS10BASE=static_cast<uint_least64_t>(std::numeric_limits<uint32_t>::digits10)+1;
    
    bool negative=false;
    std::vector<uint32_t> container;
    
    uint_least64_t getDigit(size_type k) const{
        if(k>=container.size()){
            return 0;
        }
        return container[k];
    }
    
    void normalize(){
        while(container.size()!=0 && container.back()==0){
            container.pop_back();
        }
        if(container.size()==0){
            container.push_back(0);
            negative=false;
        }
        container.shrink_to_fit();
    }
    
public:

    // Constructors
    bigint() : container{0} {}
    
    template<std::integral T>
    bigint(T n){
        if(n==0){
            container.push_back(0);
            return;
        }
        uintmax_t l;
        if(n<0){
            negative=true;
            l=static_cast<uintmax_t>(-(n+1))+1;
        } else {
            l=n;
        }
        while(l>0){
            container.push_back(l%BASE);
            l/=BASE;
        }
    }
    
    template<std::floating_point T>
    explicit bigint(T n){
        if(n>-1 && n<1){
            container.push_back(0);
            return;
        }
        long double l=n;
        if(l<0){
            negative=true;
            l=-l;
        }
        l=std::floor(l);
        while(l>=1){
            container.push_back(std::fmod(l,BASE));
            l=std::floor(l/BASE);
        }
    }

    // Unary arithmetic operators
    bigint operator+() const {return *this;}
    inline bigint operator-() const;
    
    friend inline bigint biabs(bigint n) {n.negative=false; return n;}
    
    // Comparison operators
    friend bool operator==(const bigint &a,const bigint &b) = default;
    friend std::strong_ordering operator<=>(const bigint &a,const bigint &b);
    
    // Compound assignment operators
    bigint& operator+=(const bigint &b);
    bigint& operator-=(const bigint &b);
    bigint& operator*=(const bigint &b);
    bigint& operator/=(const bigint &b);
    bigint& operator%=(const bigint &b);
    
    // Increment/decrement
    inline bigint& operator++();
    inline bigint& operator--();
    bigint operator++(int) {bigint old=*this; ++*this; return old;}
    bigint operator--(int) {bigint old=*this; --*this; return old;}
    
    // Conversion functions
    inline explicit operator bool() const;
    explicit operator std::string() const;
    
    friend bigint stobi(const std::string &n);
    
    // Debug
    void dump() const{
        if(negative){
            std::cout << "-_";
        }
        for(size_type con=container.size(); con>0; con--){
            std::cout << container[con-1] << "_";
        }
        std::cout << "[" << container.size() << "," << BASE << "," << DIGITS10BASE << "]" << "\n" << std::flush;
    }
};

bigint stobi(const std::string &str){
    bigint res;
    
    std::string::const_iterator msd=std::find_if_not(str.begin(),str.end(),[](char d){return std::isspace(d);});
    if(*msd=='+'){
        msd++;
    } else if(*msd=='-'){
        res.negative=true;
        msd++;
    }
    if(!std::isdigit(*msd)){
        throw std::invalid_argument("stobi");
    }
    msd=std::find_if(msd,str.end(),[](char d){return d!='0';});
    if(!std::isdigit(*msd)){
        res.negative=false;
        return res;
    }
    std::string::const_iterator alsd=std::find_if_not(msd,str.end(),[](char d){return std::isdigit(d);});
    
    res.container.clear();
    std::string n(msd,alsd);
    while(n.size()>bigint::DIGITS10BASE || std::stoull(std::string(n,0,bigint::DIGITS10BASE))>=bigint::BASE){
        std::string quot;
        size_type con=bigint::DIGITS10BASE;
        uint_least64_t partdivid=std::stoull(std::string(n,0,bigint::DIGITS10BASE));
        if(partdivid<bigint::BASE){
            partdivid=partdivid*10+(n[con]-'0');
            con++;
        }
        while(con<n.size()){
            quot+=partdivid/bigint::BASE+'0';
            partdivid=(partdivid%bigint::BASE)*10+(n[con]-'0');
            con++;
        }
        quot+=partdivid/bigint::BASE+'0';
        partdivid%=bigint::BASE;
        res.container.push_back(partdivid);
        n=quot;
    }
    res.container.push_back(std::stoull(n));
    
    return res;
}

inline bigint operator"" _bi (const char *n){
    std::string str=n;
    if(str.size()<=std::numeric_limits<unsigned long long>::digits10){
        return bigint(std::stoull(str));
    }
    return stobi(str);
}

inline bigint bigint::operator-() const{
    bigint flip=*this;
    if(flip!=0_bi){
        flip.negative=!(flip.negative);
    }
    return flip;
}

inline bigint& bigint::operator++(){
    *this+=1_bi;
    return *this;
}

inline bigint& bigint::operator--(){
    *this-=1_bi;
    return *this;
}
    
std::strong_ordering operator<=>(const bigint &a,const bigint &b){
    if(a.negative!=b.negative){
        return b.negative<=>a.negative;
    }
    if(a.negative==true){
        if(a.container.size()!=b.container.size()){
            return b.container.size()<=>a.container.size();
        }
        return std::lexicographical_compare_three_way(b.container.rbegin(),b.container.rend(),a.container.rbegin(),a.container.rend());
    }
    if(a.container.size()!=b.container.size()){
        return a.container.size()<=>b.container.size();
    }
    return std::lexicographical_compare_three_way(a.container.rbegin(),a.container.rend(),b.container.rbegin(),b.container.rend());
}

inline bigint::operator bool() const{
    return *this!=0_bi;
}

inline bigint operator+(bigint a,const bigint &b){
    a+=b;
    return a;
}

inline bigint operator-(bigint a,const bigint &b){
    a-=b;
    return a;
}

inline bigint operator*(bigint a,const bigint &b){
    a*=b;
    return a;
}

inline bigint operator/(bigint a,const bigint &b){
    a/=b;
    return a;
}

inline bigint operator%(bigint a,const bigint &b){
    a%=b;
    return a;
}

bigint& bigint::operator+=(const bigint &b){
    if(this==&b){
        *this*=2_bi;
        return *this;
    }
    if(b==0_bi){
        return *this;
    }
    if(negative!=b.negative){
        *this-=-b;
        return *this;
    }
    size_type digits=container.size();
    if(digits<b.container.size()){
        digits=b.container.size();
    }
    uint_least64_t rem=0;
    for(size_type k=0; k<digits; k++){
        uint_least64_t sum=rem+getDigit(k)+b.getDigit(k);
        rem=sum/BASE;
        sum%=BASE;
        if(k<container.size()){
            container[k]=sum;
        } else {
            container.push_back(sum);
        }
    }
    if(rem!=0){
        container.push_back(rem);
    }
    return *this;
}

bigint& bigint::operator-=(const bigint &b){
    if(this==&b){
        *this=0_bi;
        return *this;
    }
    if(b==0_bi){
        return *this;
    }
    if(negative!=b.negative){
        *this+=-b;
        return *this;
    }
    if(biabs(*this)<biabs(b)){
        *this=-(b-*this);
        return *this;
    }
    size_type digits=container.size();
    uint_least64_t rem=0;
    for(size_type k=0; k<digits; k++){
        uint_least64_t diff=BASE+getDigit(k)-b.getDigit(k)-rem;
        rem=1;
        if(diff>=BASE){
            diff-=BASE;
            rem=0;
        }
        container[k]=diff;
    }
    normalize();
    return *this;
}

bigint& bigint::operator*=(const bigint &b){
    if(*this==0_bi){
        return *this;
    }
    if(b==0_bi){
        *this=0_bi;
        return *this;
    }
    bool sign=(negative!=b.negative);
    bigint sum=0_bi;
    for(size_type k=0; k<b.container.size(); k++){
        bigint part;
        part.container=std::vector<uint32_t>(k,0);
        uint_least64_t rem=0;
        for(size_type j=0; j<container.size() || rem!=0; j++){
            uint_least64_t prod=(b.getDigit(k)*getDigit(j))+rem;
            rem=prod/BASE;
            prod%=BASE;
            part.container.push_back(prod);
        }
        part.normalize();
        sum+=part;
    }
    *this=sum;
    negative=sign;
    return *this;
}

bigint& bigint::operator/=(const bigint &b){
    if(b==0_bi){
        throw std::domain_error("bigint: Division by zero");
    }
    if(biabs(*this)<biabs(b)){
        *this=0_bi;
        return *this;
    }
    bool sign=(negative!=b.negative);
    bigint quot,partdivid;
    size_type con=b.container.size();
    quot.container.clear();
    partdivid.container=std::vector<uint32_t>(container.end()-con,container.end());
    con++;
    if(partdivid<b){
        partdivid.container.insert(partdivid.container.begin(),*(container.end()-con));
        con++;
    }
    while(con<=container.size()){
        uint_least64_t min=0;
        uint_least64_t max=BASE-1;
        while(max-min>1){
            uint_least64_t mid=min+(max-min)/2;
            if(partdivid-b*mid<0_bi){
                max=mid-1;
            } else {
                min=mid;
            }
        }
        uint_least64_t partquot;
        if(partdivid-b*max<0_bi){
            partquot=min;
        } else {
            partquot=max;
        }
        partdivid-=b*partquot;
        quot.container.push_back(partquot);
        partdivid.container.insert(partdivid.container.begin(),*(container.end()-con));
        partdivid.normalize();
        con++;
    }
    uint_least64_t min=0;
    uint_least64_t max=BASE-1;
    while(max-min>1){
        uint_least64_t mid=min+(max-min)/2;
        if(partdivid-b*mid<0_bi){
            max=mid-1;
        } else {
            min=mid;
        }
    }
    uint_least64_t partquot;
    if(partdivid-b*max<0_bi){
        partquot=min;
    } else {
        partquot=max;
    }
    quot.container.push_back(partquot);
    std::reverse(quot.container.begin(),quot.container.end());
    *this=quot;
    negative=sign;
    return *this;
}

bigint& bigint::operator%=(const bigint &b){
    *this=*this-(*this/b)*b;
    return *this;
}

bigint::operator std::string() const{
    std::string str;
    if(*this==0_bi){
        str+='0';
        return str;
    }
    bigint n=*this;
    n.negative=false;
    while(n>0_bi){
        str+=(n%10_bi).container[0]+'0';
        n/=10_bi;
    }
    if(negative){
        str+='-';
    }
    std::reverse(str.begin(),str.end());
    return str;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const bigint &n){
    os << static_cast<std::string>(n);
    return os;
}

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream &is, bigint &n){
    std::string str;
    is >> str;
    try{
        n=stobi(str);
    } catch(std::invalid_argument&){
        is.setstate(std::ios::failbit);
    }
    return is;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this code with a simple `main()`:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    bigint a(1'048'576);
    bigint b = a*a*a*a;
    std::cout
        << b/a/a/a
        << '\n';
}
```

This allocated 47,580 bytes more than `std::cout << '\n';`, which seems like much more than necessary.  We should investigate just why there's so much copying going on, particularly as the class appears move-friendly.

One possibility is that the literals `0_bi` and `1_bi` that appear so often could be usefully be replaced with static constants.

---

Style: the code is hard to read with no spaces around operators.

---

> ```
> using std::uint_least64_t;
> using std::uint32_t;
> using std::uintmax_t;
> using size_type = uint_least64_t;
> ```

These are all in the global scope, and therefore affect every translation unit that includes this header.  They would make more sense as member types of `bigint`.

---

`BASE` and `DIGITS10BASE` are C++ identifiers, so don't write them in all-caps - standard convention reserves that for macros (which need special attention because they don't obey the rules of scope, and expand arguments rather than evaluating them).

---

> ```
>     while(container.size()!=0 && container.back()==0){
>         container.pop_back();
>     }
>     if(container.size()==0){
>         container.push_back(0);
>         negative=false;
>     }
> ```

`container.size() == 0` is more usually written `container.empty()`.  I'm not sure I like removing the last zero and then reinstating when necessary (although I can see it's a convenient way to convert `-0` to `+0`).

---

I like the care you've taken to avoid overflow here:

> ```
>         l=static_cast<uintmax_t>(-(n+1))+1;
> ```

It might be worth a comment pointing out that we know `n` is a signed type, and therefore the result will fit comfortably in a `std::uintmax_t`.

---

I think we could use `std::remquo` here:

> ```
>         container.push_back(std::fmod(l,BASE));
>         l=std::floor(l/BASE);
> ```

That would become

```
        container.push_back(std::remquo(l, BASE, &l));
```

On systems with binary floating-point, there's no need to promote the argument to `long double`, as we've ensured that `BASE` is a power of 2, making the division exact.  We could could make this code more efficient on the majority of systems, saving the promotion only for those where `std::numeric_limits<T>::radix` is not a power of two.

---

`biabs()` looks like it should be called `abs()`, to enable it to be used in generic functions interchangeably with the standard integer types.  Similarly, `stobi()` should be `stoi()`.  These would both work better if we had an enclosing namespace.

---

The `dump()` member seems to be no longer used, so I wouldn't provide it.

---

`stobi()` would be better taking a `std::string_view`.  I think it could also `reserve()` a reasonable guess at the required vector length to reduce reallocation.

`stobi()` should probably ignore `'` in input, so we can read grouped numbers:

```
auto a = 1'048'576;
auto b = 1'048'576_bi;
assert(a == b);  // fails; b==1
```

---

The duplication in `operator<=>` could be reduced, by simply swapping pointers:

```
std::strong_ordering operator<=>(const bigint &a, const bigint &b)
{
    if (a.negative != b.negative) {
        return b.negative <=> a.negative;
    }
    auto const *da = &a.container;
    auto const *db = &b.container;
    if (a.negative) {
        std::swap(da, db);
    }
    if (da->size() != db->size()) {
        return da->size() <=> db->size();
    }
    return std::lexicographical_compare_three_way(da->rbegin(), da->rend(), db->rbegin(), db->rend());
}
```

(I also eliminated the redundant comparison of a `bool` with `true`).

---

Instead of comparing with `0_bi`, our `operator bool()` could directly check the array contents, with much less work:

```
return container.size() > 1 && container.front();
```